# Inserting mismatched columns into table

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to select all data from SALES_TABLE1 into SALES_TABLE2

TABLE2 is identical to TABLE1 except that it has one extra column, SETTLEMENTDATE, which I want to remain null.

```
INSERT INTO SALES_TABLE2
        (SALEDATE,
         POSID,
         STAFFID,
         VALUE,
         SETTLEMENTDATE)
SELECT   SALEDATE,
         POSID,
         STAFFID,
         VALUE,
         NULL
FROM SALES_TABLE1;
```

Tried it a few different ways, only ever getting

> "Error(50,26): PL/SQL: ORA-01789: query block has incorrect number of result columns"

Any help for a poor, frazzle brain?

Comment: It should work. My guess would be that the column types are not identical or the query you posted here isn't exactly the query that is giving the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should've worked already, but here's another way you could do this. Simply omit the column in the column list.

```
INSERT INTO SALES_TABLE2
        (SALEDATE,
         POSID,
         STAFFID,
         VALUE)
SELECT   SALEDATE,
         POSID,
         STAFFID,
         VALUE
FROM SALES_TABLE1;
```

Comment: Thanks. Stupid me, just realised I had a MINUS statement attached that was wrecking it. Appreciate the help